# Is there a way to add a Geopackage in QGIS 2.18.20 like QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

Is there a way to add a Geopackage into QGIS 2.18.20 that is similar to the approach taken in QGIS 3?

The below is a screen grab from QGIS 3.0.3

[image]

When I drag and drop into QGIS 2.18.20 it gives me the option to add all layers but the layer names are given a prefix of Geopackage and I don't want this.

Comment: Do you want to add a GeoPackage file under that section in the Browser, or do you want to import layers in a specific GeoPackage file?

Comment: Use the browser if possible?

Comment: Doesn't right-click and _New Connection_ work to link to a preexisting GeoPackage file?

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear that the screen grab is QGIS 3.0.3, I cannot seem to find a Geopackage option in QGIS 2.18.20 in the browser panel.

Comment: Use "DB Manager"

Comment: Thanks, I knew you could use that but just wanted to know if the above was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DB Manager seems to be the only way, since GeoPackages are not supported natively in 2.18. DB-Manager is a buildin-plugin with extended functionality for qgis and gives you the possibility to use GeoPackages in QGIS 2.18.